# Textbox & Cell Format VBA

Tags: vba, userform, cell-formatting

I have a user form with a text box that allows me to enter a date, this date then copies into a column/cell formatted as a long date “1 Jan 2020”. However, when I enter a date as “01/01/2020” into the user form text box, the date does not correct to the cell format. Does anyone have any ideas on how I could fix this? This is the code:

```
Dim lrow As Long
Dim LO As ListObject
Dim LEO As Range
Set ws = Worksheets("2020_Data")
Set LO = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
'lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B") .End(xlUp). .Offset(1, 0) .Row
With LO.Range.Columns(2)
Set LEO = .Find(what:="", after:=.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
    searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext)
If Not LEO Is Nothing Then
    lrow = LEO.Row
'        MsgBox LEO.Row 'First empty row at column B
End If
End With
'rw = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookInValues) .Row + 
1
With ws
   .Cells(lrow, "B").Value = DateValue(Me.TextBox6.Value)
   .Cells(lrow, "C").Value = DateValue(Me.TextBox21.Value)
   .Cells(lrow, "F").Value = Me.ComboBox2.Value
   .Cells(lrow, "G").Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value
   .Cells(lrow, "I").Value = Me.TextBox16.Value
   .Cells(lrow, "H").Value = Me.TextBox17.Value
   .Cells(lrow, "J").Value = Me.TextBox18.Value
End With
 'Clear Input Controls.
 Me.TextBox6 = ""
 Me.TextBox21 = ""
 Me.ComboBox2 = ""
 Me.ComboBox3 = ""
 Me.TextBox16 = ""
 Me.TextBox17 = ""
 Me.TextBox18 = "" 
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: It's because the TextBox hold a string and a date is, in essence, a number.  Try ` .Cells(lrow, "J").Value = DateValue(Me.TextBox18.Value)`

Comment: Hi @Variatus, Thanks for that it's working in essence. However, I keep getting an error when I try the code on both: textbox6 & 21. It seems I can run the code on both textbox's but then I need to input data in the userform in both textbox's. would there be a way where I can run the above code without having to fill data into boxes? Giving me the option of either entering only a start date or both a start and end date? Thanks!

Comment: Pleas edit question to include relevant codes only. Anyhow, you can try using 3 Textboxes for month, day and year respectively. Then construct the date in the back ground using `DateSerial` before dumping it to the worksheet.

Comment: Please [edit] the post to show which inputs work and which inputs it fails and what is expected on those cases.

Answer (score 0):

The code below must be installed in your UserForm's code module. It will run when you complete the change in TextBox6.

```
Private Sub TextBox6_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

Dim TbxVal As String

With TextBox6
    TbxVal = .Value
    If IsDate(TbxVal) Then
        Cells(6, "B").Value = DateValue(TbxVal)
        With TextBox21
            If Len(.Value) = 0 Then
                ' this command would prevent any event procedure
                ' attached to TextBox21 from being executed
                ' based on the entry about to be made.
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                .Value = Format(DateValue(TbxVal) + 6, "dd mmm, yyyy")
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Enter a valid date", vbExclamation, "Invalid date format"
        .SetFocus
        .SelStart = 0
        .SelLength = Len(TbxVal)
        Cancel = True
    End If
End With
```

End Sub

It will first check if you entered a date and complain if your entry wasn't understood. Then it will write the entry to the sheet using the `DateValue`, not the text string. Next it will write that same DateValue increased by 6 and then formatted as a date string to TextBox21. Observe how the string from TextBox6 is converted to a true date (a number), used in a calculation, and then converted back to a string that can be fed to the TextBox.

You may wonder why the value of TextBox6 is assigned to a variable instead of being used directly. For one, the addressing is easier that way. For another, it's easier to give a meaningful name to the variable. And, finally, accessing a variable is faster than referring to the user form (the same holds true for variables stored in worksheets).